# Different search results with Wordpress and Relevanssi

Tags: search, plugins

I am new here in the forum and in the WordPress world and need help with following problem.

It's about a website that is using WordPress and several plugins like Avada, Fusion Builder, Fusion Slider and Releveanssi.

For the website we implemented a Custom Post Type ("Project") with different taxonomies.

The website contains two search fields. One in the header and one on a sub-page. The last one contains an additional filter, which only account posts of the type "project".

If I now search for a term (contained in the title of a project) the filtered searchfield get results. The unfiltered searchfield (-> suppoerted by Relevanssi) get no results.

In the settings of Relevanssi I all Custom Post Types and all Taxonomies are considered for index creation. Just like all Customs Fields.
The index was regenerated, but the two search fields still provide different results.

I am thankful for every hint!

Best regards Markus

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved. It was the Avada plugin. In the search settings, the default tags under ***Search Results Content*** act like a filter so that the Custom Post Types contained in the Relevanssi Index are not taken into account.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: I removed all Avada default tags which controls the type of content that displays in search results.